# deleting every nth element from a list until 1 element remains

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a numlist 1 to x and I should delete every nth element until 1 remains similar to the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) but instead of going in a circle, you start iterating from the beginning. If you had a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and n = 3, first iteration removes 3,6,9. Second iteration removes 4 (would be 2 if it were in a circle) and then 8. Third iteration removes 5 and so on until n > len(players) then it could go in a circle.

```
players = list(range(1, int(input()) + 1))
n = (int(input()) - 1)
innocent = (n) % len(players)

while len(players) > 1:
    loser = players.pop(innocent)
    innocent = (innocent + n) % len(players)

print(*players)
```

This code deletes every nth element until 1 is left but it goes in a circle and doesn't iterate from the beginning when it reaches the end of the list each time. How would I change it to do as I explained above?

Comment: If you always start at the beginning of the list, you will always end up with `n-1` players left in the list, so you'll never get to 1 player unless `n=2`

Comment: @Nick Isn't that only when len(players) > n?

Comment: Yes; if `len(players) < n` the list will remain unchanged

Comment: @Nick maybe change it to only go in a circle once n > len(players) ?

Comment: That could work.

Comment: So you can start with `players = players[:n-1] if n > 1 else players` to reduce the number of players below `n`. After that, you either need to use your current algorithm or remove `n % len(players)`th player in a loop, depending on what do you want.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa just tried it and it gives me an index error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would solve your problem
use a while loop `if len(A) >= n` delete nth elements
```if len(A) < n and len(A) >1`` delete the last element.

```
A = [h for h in range(1,11)]
n = 3
potentials = [i-1 for i in range(len(A)) if i%n == 0][1:]
B = {}
k = 0

while len(A) > 1: 
    if len(A) >= n:
        A = [A[j] for j in range(len(A)) if j not in potentials]
        B[k] = A
        k +=1
    else :  
        A = A[:-1]
        B[k] = A
        k +=1

print(B)
Out: 
{0: [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10],
 1: [1, 2, 5, 7, 10],
 2: [1, 2, 7, 10],
 3: [1, 2, 10],
 4: [1, 2],
 5: [1]}
```

To adjust to your problem

```
players = list(range(1, int(input()) + 1))
n = (int(input()) - 1)

potentials = [i-1 for i in range(len(players)) if i%n == 0][1:] # position of elements that will be deleted in each iteration

while len(players ) > 1:
    if  len(players ) >= n: 
        losers =  [players[j] for j in range(len(players)) if j in potentials] #I assume losers are the ones being deleted
        players = [players[j] for j in range(len(players)) if j not in potentials]
    else: 
        losers =  players[-1]
        players = players[:-1]
```

Comment: I get that the dictionary is the list after each iteration but 2 elements still remain in list A when there should be 1 also the variables are a bit weird with the mix between capital and small letters but that's fine.

Comment: One way is to use anotther while loop right after the first one, which checks for condition of ```len(Player)>1```

Comment: @CSuser can you confirm if this works for you?

Comment: shouldnt iteration 5 return 2 since it goes 1 then 2 then 1 and gets rid of 1? It iterates over 1 and 2 and there is still 1 iteration left so it goes over 1 and then deletes it. This returns 1 no matter what i think.

Comment: @CSuser, I dont get you, what do you expect to be done after you are left with ```n-1``` elements? Should the last element be deleted or the first element? Your post only specified to the delete the```nth``` element but once you are left with ```n-1``` you need to decide which ones you delete first. If you want to delete the starting elements first then just change the position of slicing. instead of ```player = player[:-1]``` use ```player = player[1:]```

Comment: Ah ok my badI misunderstood the code. I'l just do that slight change thanks for the answer!